How to share a boolean in multiple components, and allow changes to be applied to all components used in
In my application am using cookies for authentication using HttpContext. For that reason i have to disable InteractiveServer globally and only use it in pages that are not using HttpContext since using it in MainLayout.Razor causes this error
InvalidOperationException: Cannot pass the parameter 'Body' to component 'MainLayout' with rendermode 'InteractiveServerRenderMode'. This is because the parameter is of the delegate type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment', which is arbitrary code and cannot be serialized.
so i choose to create a sub component that will be called in MainLayout which will have buttons that can be interacted with, in this instance a Drawer icon button. so i created an AppBar.Razor
the javascript i just added to be seeing the state of the Open(bool) in console, which in the browser is changing when invoked.
AppBar.Razor
@inject NavigationService NavigationService
@inject DrawerStateService DrawerStateService
@using System.ComponentModel;
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using SarisApplication.Services
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime


<MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" @onclick="ToggleOpen" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> OpenChanged { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        DrawerStateService.Open = true;
    }
    async Task ToggleOpen()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        DrawerStateService.SetOpen(!DrawerStateService.Open);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", DrawerStateService.Open);
        StateHasChanged();

    }

}


my MainLayout.Razor is
again in this i added another piece of code to be showing the state of the Open
@using SarisApplication.Components.Layout
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using SarisApplication.Services
@using SarisApplication.Components
@rendermode InteractiveServer

@inject NavigationService NavigationService
@inject DrawerStateService DrawerStateService

<MyMudThemeProvider />

<MyMudProviders />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <NotAuthorized>
        </NotAuthorized>
        <Authorized>
            <MudAppBar Elevation="1" Color="Color.Inherit">
                <AppBar />
            </MudAppBar>
            <MudDrawer Open="@DrawerStateService.Open" PreserveOpenState="true" Elevation="1" Variant="@DrawerVariant.Responsive">
                <NavMenu />
            </MudDrawer>
        </Authorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
    <MudMainContent>
        <CascadingValue Value="@DrawerStateService.Open">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
        @if (@DrawerStateService.Open)
        {
            <span>
                "Drawer is open"
            </span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>
                "Drawer is closed"
            </span>
        }


    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DrawerStateService.OnOpenChanged += HandleOpenChanged;
    }

    private void HandleOpenChanged(bool isOpen)
    {
        DrawerStateService.Open = isOpen;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DrawerStateService.OnOpenChanged -= HandleOpenChanged;
    }
}

and finally my NavMenu.Razor
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DrawerStateService DrawerStateService
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using SarisApplication.Services

<MudDrawerHeader>
    @if (DrawerStateService.Open)
    {
        <img src="/images/logo.png" width="90" height="90" alt="Logo">
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="/images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Logo">
    }
</MudDrawerHeader>
<MudNavMenu>
</MudNavMenu>

@code
{
    private string? currentUrl;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DrawerStateService.Open = true;

        currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }

    private void OnLocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(e.Location);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
    }
}

So the intention is to allow the Drawer to be Minimised and Maxmised when the MudButtonIcon is clicked as of now it is now.
What am i missing and what should i do to achieve this?
Thanks for your help in advance.
